# How to order and keep common indexes from two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `DataFrames`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from scipy import stats


ctrl=u"""probegenes,sample1,sample2,sample3
1415777_at Pnliprp1,20,0.00,11
1415884_at Cela3b,47,0.00,100
1415805_at Clps,17,0.00,55
1115805_at Ckkk,77,10.00,5.5
"""

df_ctrl = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(ctrl),index_col='probegenes')

test=u"""probegenes,sample1,sample2,sample3
1415777_at Pnliprp1,20.1,10.00,22.3
1415805_at Clps,7,3.00,1.5
1415884_at Cela3b,47,2.01,30"""

df_test = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(test),index_col='probegenes')
```

They look like this:

```
In [35]: df_ctrl
Out[35]:
                     sample1  sample2  sample3
probegenes
1415777_at Pnliprp1       20        0     11.0
1415884_at Cela3b         47        0    100.0
1415805_at Clps           17        0     55.0
1115805_at Ckkk           77       10      5.5

In [36]: df_test
Out[36]:
                     sample1  sample2  sample3
probegenes
1415777_at Pnliprp1     20.1    10.00     22.3
1415805_at Clps          7.0     3.00      1.5
1415884_at Cela3b       47.0     2.01     30.0
```

I'd like to:

1. Get a common `index` for both `DataFrame`
2. Reorder both `DataFrame` identically.

Hence, in the end I get two new `DataFrame`:

```
new_df_ctrl 

                     sample1  sample2  sample3
probegenes
1415884_at Cela3b         47        0    100.0
1415805_at Clps           17        0     55.0
1415777_at Pnliprp1       20        0     11.0


new_df_test

                     sample1  sample2  sample3
probegenes
1415884_at Cela3b       47.0     2.01     30.0
1415805_at Clps          7.0     3.00      1.5
1415777_at Pnliprp1     20.1    10.00     22.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `join` with the parameter `how='inner'` to get the common index.  Then just reindex each dataframe using this common index.

```
idx = df_ctrl.join(df_test, rsuffix='_', how='inner').index

>>> df_ctrl.reindex(idx)
                     sample1  sample2  sample3
probegenes                                    
1415777_at Pnliprp1       20        0       11
1415805_at Clps           17        0       55
1415884_at Cela3b         47        0      100

>>> df_test.reindex(idx)
                     sample1  sample2  sample3
probegenes                                    
1415777_at Pnliprp1     20.1    10.00     22.3
1415805_at Clps          7.0     3.00      1.5
1415884_at Cela3b       47.0     2.01     30.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pd.Index.intersection()` and select using `.loc[]` or `.reindex()`. Use `.sort_values()` on the `index` to get the desired ordering:

```
idx = df_ctrl.index.intersection(df_test.index).sort_values(ascending=False)

df_ctrl.loc[idx]

                     sample1  sample2  sample3
probegenes                                    
1415884_at Cela3b         47      0.0    100.0
1415805_at Clps           17      0.0     55.0
1415777_at Pnliprp1       20      0.0     11.0

df_test.loc[idx]

                     sample1  sample2  sample3
probegenes                                    
1415884_at Cela3b       47.0     2.01     30.0
1415805_at Clps          7.0     3.00      1.5
1415777_at Pnliprp1     20.1    10.00     22.3
```